# Why is Gmail showing me a Skull?

Tags: gmail

I noticed today a skull at the bottom-right in my Gmail Inbox.

This occurs at Google Chrome, Firefox and IE10.

Why is this so?

What does

> Component Spy  Mole Component Spy  Data Spy  Channel Spy  Reload CSS 
>   LateLoad Spy  AppContext Spy

mean?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an internal Gmail component, used for development of the web UI. I can't find any comments or explanations on *why* it shows up to outside users, but a Google employee has recognized this issue on [Google Product Forums](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/PXN5qszd3_8;context-place=forum/gmail).

Comment: **"I can confirm that this issue is purely superficial though, so no need to worry"** is a little bit low, isn't it?